# call to undefined function error in php

Tags: php

I am trying to get friend-list from `facebook` using Graph API and PHP I have tired  below code its showing error

> Error : Undefined function d() in `D:\xampp\htdocs\kenshinkan-new\kenshinkan\facebook.php on line 37`

How to fix this error ?

```
 <body>
<?php

    //facebook application configuration
    $fbconfig['appid' ] = "45675467245672462456262";
    $fbconfig['secret'] = "afdgadgdagdagadfg";

    try{
        include_once ('.\facebook-php-sdk-master\src\facebook.php');
    }
    catch(Exception $o){

        print_r($o);

    }
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
      'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
      'cookie' => true,
    ));

    $user       = $facebook->getUser();
    $loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
            array(
                'scope'         => 'email'
            )
    );

    if ($user) {
      try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        $user_friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
        $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        d($e); 
        $user = null;
      }
    }

    if (!$user) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
        exit;
    }

    $total_friends = count($user_friends['data']);
    echo 'Total friends: '.$total_friends.'.<br />';
    $start = 0;
    while ($start < $total_friends) {
        echo $user_friends['data'][$start]['name'];
        echo '<br />';
        $start++;
    }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to define  d($e);  or include the file where it is defined!

Answer (score 3):

Your error is right here..

```
catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        d($e);  //This is your error. What do you suppose function d() would do?
        $user = null;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, either adding the `d()` function, or removing the `d($e);` call to the function (which is not there)?

Also, you'll only be able to retrieve those friends which are also using your app, not all.

Comment: i removed that function Running the code   error fixed but that file loading not  going inside the  site

Comment: What does that even mean? I don't think you correctly instanciate the PHP SDK, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/5.0.0#installation

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `d()` - is a short-hand function to dump/log exception. 
It's definitely created by that person, who's code you took :) 
You can remove this line or define that function. Could be smth like:

```
function d($e) {
  error_log($e->getMessage());
}
```

**error_log()** — Send an error message to the defined error handling routines (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php)